# How can i create pdf with jspdf from html and text?

Tags: javascript, jspdf

I need to print my html contet and text together, I tried with the below code, but the text that am added is not printing in the PDF. Its only print the html contents. Please help me to solve this issue....

```
    pdf = new jsPDF('l', 'mm', 'ledger'),
    specialElementHandlers = {
      '#editor': function( element, renderer ) {
          return true;
      }
};
pdf.fromHTML(
      $('#customers').get(0) // HTML element
    , 15  // x coord
    , 0.5  // y coord
    , {
          'width': 3000 // was 7.5, max width of content on PDF
        , elementHandlers: specialElementHandlers
    }
);
pdf.text(35, 25, "test");
pdf.save( filename ); 
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think your missing the syntax here 
What you have done here 
pdf.text(35, 25, "test"); 
Instead use this: 
pdf.text("test",35, 25);
(Where the 35 stands X axis an 25 stands Y axis in pdf document).

Comment: Thanks jones.. but if i added the text after adding html then its not working. that is need to add the code pdf.text("test",35, 25); before   pdf.fromHTML(....    .Otherwise it not printing.. Please hlp me to solve this issue....

Answer (score 7):

you must use the full sintax of function:

```
doc.fromHTML(HTML, x, y, settings, callback, margins);
```

Using callback you can add a function that executes on fromHtml complete.

In your code:

```
pdf = new jsPDF('l', 'mm', 'ledger'),
    specialElementHandlers = {
      '#editor': function( element, renderer ) {
          return true;
      }
};
pdf.fromHTML(
      $('#customers').get(0) // HTML element
    , 15  // x coord
    , 0.5  // y coord
    , {
          'width': 3000 // was 7.5, max width of content on PDF
        , elementHandlers: specialElementHandlers
    },
    myfunc,
    {
        top : 25,
        bottom : 25
    }
);

function myfunc(){
    pdf.text(35, 25, "test");
    pdf.save( filename ); 
}
```